# Parent process has multiple child and 2 child process has a child process

Tags: c, fork

I have a parent process from which i want to create 4 child processes, and 2 of the child processes has one child process each.

I was able to create the 4 child processes from the parent. But when i try to create the child processes for 2 child process i have an infinite loop.
I used the loop for to create the 4 processes and added a condition which is when the second child process and fourth child process are created, create a child process for each one.

- Parent has (child1 chil2 child3 child 4)
- Child2 has (child 5 child6)

Source:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sched.h> 
#include <sys/time.h> 
#include <sys/resource.h> 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
    int i; 
    for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++) 
    { 
        if(fork() == 0)
        {
            printf("process %d and his parent is %d \n",
                getpid(), getppid());

            if(i = 1)
            {
                if(fork() == 0)
                {
                    printf("process %d and his parent is %d \n",
                        getpid(), getppid());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post minimal code. Can't see what you did wrong otherwise.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int i;   
for(i =0; i<=3; i++) 
    { 
        if(fork() ==0) 
         {  
             printf("process %d and his parent is %d \n", getpid(),getppid());
  if(i=1){
   if(fork() ==0) {  
                printf("process %d and his parent is %d \n", getpid(),getppid()); 
    break;
             } 

   }
          } 

    }

  return 0;
}

Comment: The system works! Already two reopen votes now that you posted code. In a comment no less :)

Comment: `if(i = 1)` is always true. You probably meant `if(i == 1)`. This is why you need to post code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues.  First:

```
if(i = 1)
```

You're using `=` which is an assignment instead of `==` which compares for equality.  What's actually happening here is that `i` is being assigned the value of 1 and that value (1) is being evaluated in boolean context, which is always true.  So each child enters the `if` block and forks its own child.

Use the comparision operator instead, and also check if `i` is either 1 or 3 if you want the second and fourth children to also `fork`:

```
if ((i == 1) || (i == 3))
```

Second, at the end of the `if(fork()==0)` block, the child process continues on for the next iteration of the `for` loop.  So each child will invoke the parent behavior of looping and forking.  This results in many more processes being created than expected.

You need to add an `exit` statement at the end of this block.  Also, be sure to `#include <stdlib.h>` for the definition of `exit`:

```
if (fork()==0)
{
    ...
    exit(0);
}
```

One other thing that would be useful: At the end of the loop, have the parent `wait` for all children to finish.  Otherwise, it may `exit` before its children and the children would report process ` as the parent

So after these fixes, the code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        if(fork() == 0)
        {
            printf("process %d and his parent is %d \n",
                getpid(), getppid());

            if ((i == 1) || (i == 3))
            {
                if(fork() == 0)
                {
                    printf("process %d and his parent is %d \n",
                        getpid(), getppid());
                    exit(0);
                }
                while (wait(NULL) != -1);
            }
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    while (wait(NULL) != -1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning value 1 to `i` instead of comparison.

```
if(i = 1)
```

should be

```
if(i == 1)
```

if you intended to test equality of `i` and value 1. Assigning to the loop control variable creates an infinite loop when `i` is always set to value 1.

However, based on your description that states you want to create a child process for the second and fourth of the 4 initial child processes, this does not yet accomplish what you are after.

Given the constraints of 4 original children, you can write

```
if((i & 1) != 0)
```

which evaluates to `true` for values 1 and 3 where the lowest bit of the binary representation of `i` is set.